# How to modify the class file?

Tags: java

I was working on the project in eclipse in which I have added this maven dependency for PDFBOX

```
Maven dependency

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I was getting the error on some pdf file as:

```
Parsing Error, Skipping Object
java.io.IOException: expected='endstream' actual='' org.apache.pdfbox.io.PushBackInputStream@1b8d77fe
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSStream(BaseParser.java:439)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parseObject(PDFParser.java:552)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:184)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1088)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1053)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:74)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:135)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:357)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.BinaryParser.parse(BinaryParser.java:37)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.handleBinary(WebCrawler.java:223)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.processPage(WebCrawler.java:460)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

So when I google it, I found there was some bug in BaseParser.java file, So they have given the patch(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-195) for this java file only.. So my question is how can I modify this java file only.. I can see the BaseParser.class file in eclipse as I have attached the source doc for that PDFBOX-Issue. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: That issue you are referring to is fixed in 0.8.0 and you are using version 1.6.0 of that library. Are you really sure that this issue is related to your exception?

Comment: Make sure it's actually version 1.6.0 that appears in your built project, and not some older one, that might cut it as a dependency to one of your modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that [BaseParser.java](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/feedparser/apidocs/org/apache/commons/feedparser/BaseParser.html) is an Apache file, there is absolutely no reason why you cannot download the source, make your changes and re-compile it. I have done this with Apache code in the past. It was pretty straight forward and took me only a few minutes. Remember to submit your fix back to Apache so that way it will be included in the release.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- create subclass manual (and use it if it possible)
- download source, fix it, recompile, and finally, overwrite it in jar
- create subclass programmaticly (using cglib or asm)
- download only BasicParser, mock all depends (just create empty class files with needs methods), recompile it and put in jar (or ./ext ./endorsed dir in jvm, if you want)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one doesn't modify a class file directly, they download the source code and then rebuild the class file with `javac`.  Yes, it is possible to modify class files without doing such a thing; but, patch files are not generally binary patch files, they are generally source code patch files.

Stefanglase has mentioned that the release you are working with should have the patch applied, but there is a small chance that a recent change reintroduced the issue.  You might want to verify that you're not solving the wrong problem before you get too deep into it.

On the rare odds that you really want to modify a binary, you open it with a hexadecimal editor, or a hexeditor for short.  Basically this allows you to set any byte in the file to any value, which means you must have a strong knowledge of the file's internal format, what is allowed / disallowed, and how to make allowable changes that actually implement your expected behavior.  In short, you'll be doing a compiler's work manually, by hand.

It can be done, but it is the sort of task that generally requires a lot of knowledge, and few people have that knowledge already, so the costs of learning that knowledge and successfully implementing the change is likely much higher than rebuilding from available patched source.  Even the costs of successfully implementing the change with the knowledge of the general principals and techniques already present isn't something that one can say with certainty is less than the costs of rebuilding the entire library with patched source.

Good Luck.